# How to enable bootstrap popover feature?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I have a question with bootstrap v3 popover feature.

I know it might be an old question and I read through other threads and tried their ways but still don't know how to get it to work.

I have HTML like

```
<button type="button" class="testBtn btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on left
</button>
```

JS

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({trigger: 'hover','placement': 'top'});
$('.testBtn').popover();
```

I have also included

```
/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

and

```
boostrap.tooltip.js
```

in my code. I can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `tooltip.js` you should include `popover.js`.

Comment: I can't seem to find the popover.js and the bootstrap site says it needs tooltip.js to enable popover. +1

Comment: @FlyingCat There is `popover.js`: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/js